# 415: Unsupported Media Type in Apache Tomee Plumee

Tags: java, json, spring, rest

i have a project in Spring Framework.All codes are ok and working in Glassfish but when i deploy it on Apache Tomcat Plumee and get this exception.What is the wrong with project?
My code is this:

```
import az.Vortex.SpringDevelopers.dto.MailDTO;
import az.Vortex.SpringDevelopers.dto.UserAddResponse;
import az.Vortex.SpringDevelopers.dto.UserDTO;
import az.Vortex.SpringDevelopers.dto.UserLoginResponseObject;
import az.Vortex.SpringDevelopers.model.User;
import az.Vortex.SpringDevelopers.model.UserRole;
import az.Vortex.SpringDevelopers.model.UserSession;
import az.Vortex.SpringDevelopers.response.CustomException;
import az.Vortex.SpringDevelopers.response.ResponseDTO;
import az.Vortex.SpringDevelopers.service.UserService;
import az.Vortex.SpringDevelopers.service.UserSessionService;
import az.Vortex.SpringDevelopers.utils.MailUtil;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.xml.ws.Response;
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
import utils.AuthorizationUtil;
import utils.EmailValidator;
import utils.SecurityUtils;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("users")
public class UserController {

@RequestMapping(value = "login", method = RequestMethod.POST,
        consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody
ResponseDTO loginUser(@RequestBody UserDTO userDto) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("login=" + userDto);
    ResponseDTO result = new ResponseDTO();

    String exStr = "";
    if (userDto.getEmail() == null || !EmailValidator.validate(userDto.getEmail())) {
        exStr = "email is not filled right";
    }

    if (userDto.getPassword() == null || userDto.getPassword().length() == 0) {
        exStr += " password is not filled right";
    }

    if (exStr.length() > 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(exStr);
    }

    User userTemp = new User();
    userTemp.setEmail(userDto.getEmail());

    userTemp = userService.getUser(userTemp);

    if (userTemp == null) {
        throw new CustomException("This email doesn't exist", "Email or password is not right");
    }
    System.out.println(userDto.getPassword());
    userTemp.setPassword(userDto.getPassword());

    userTemp = userService.getUserForLogin(userTemp);
    if (userTemp == null) {
        throw new CustomException("Password is incorrect,owner email:" + userDto.getEmail(), "Email or password is not right");
    }
    result.setResponseObject(addOrUpdateSession(userTemp));
    result.setSuccessMessage("Successfully logged in");
    return result;
}
```

}

> Apr 16, 2016 8:14:54 PM az.Vortex.SpringDevelopers.filters.CustomExceptionHandler handleAllException
>   SEVERE: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/json' not supported
>   org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/json' not supported
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.readWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:149)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.readWithMessageConverters(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:180)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:95)
>       at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:77)
>       at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:162)
>       at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:123)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
>       at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
>       at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
>       at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
>       at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
>       at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
>       at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
>       at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
>       at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
>       at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
>       at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
>       at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:436)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Apr 16, 2016 8:14:54 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver doResolveHandlerMethodException
SEVERE: Failed to invoke @ExceptionHandler method: public az.Vortex.SpringDevelopers.response.ResponseDTO az.Vortex.SpringDevelopers.filters.CustomExceptionHandler.handleAllException(java.lang.Exception,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:157)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:90)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:189)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:69)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:122)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.doResolveHandlerMethodException(ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.java:321)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver.doResolveException(AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver.java:60)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerExceptionResolverComposite.resolveException(HandlerExceptionResolverComposite.java:73)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processHandlerException(DispatcherServlet.java:1148)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:985)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:939)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:436)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved my problem.I added this dependency:

> ```
>   <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
>         <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
>         <version>1.9.10</version>
>     </dependency>
> ```